# May i add this in this list?

Tags: list, set, addition, intersection

i got this code, and i want to add the print in "lista_3"
how can i do it? Thanks!

lista_1 = ["h",'o','l','a',' ', 'm','u','n','d','o']

lista_2 = ["h",'o','l','a',' ', 'l','u','n','a']

lista_3 = []

set_1 = set(lista_1)
set_2 = set(lista_2)

print(set_1.intersection(set_2))

Comment: can you share the input you have and the output you need?

Comment: output: {'u', 'a', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'l'}

i need that in lista_3 (is not sorted but i dont care xD)

Thanks for replying, sry this is my first time asking something about python, i'm learning

Comment: don't worry, btw you have the solution in your question, don't you?

Comment: you're right, i just read the practical work and i dont need (lista_3) xD, thanks again for the fast answer, and.. sry for my english